# Center ConTeXt table horizontally

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, context

Although my [table](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table) is only so wide and inside a `alignment[middle]` environment, it doesn’t get centered and stays left aligned. (For ConTeXtians: right aligned :))

I tried a hack and add an empty paragraph column, but empty columns appearantly get ignored.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on which table environment you are using. With tables and natural tables, `\midaligned` centers the table:

```
\starttext
\midaligned
  {\startTABLE
    \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
    \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
    \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
    \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \NR
  \stopTABLE}

\stoptext
```

or

```
\starttext
\midaligned
  {\starttable[|l|l|l|]
     \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \AR
     \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \AR
     \NC A \NC B \NC C \NC \AR
   \stoptable}

\stoptext
```

There is no environment version of `\midaligned`, but you can easily create your own if you want:

```
\def\startmidaligned
    {\midaligned\bgroup}

\def\stopmidaligned
    {\egroup}
```

Comment: I edited the question for which table I use. Something is wrong with your answer, though: You use `TABLE`s here, but the syntax of `table`s. natual `TABLE`s start like this: `\bTABLE \bTR \bTD`. Is there an environment for `midaligned`?

Comment: The TABLE macros also support the old style syntax. See [context wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE#TABLEs_with_old_table_syntax). Using `\midaligned` also works with `table` macros.

Comment: didn’t know the further, thanks! do you know what the difference between `\midaligned` and `\startalignment[middle]` is?

Comment: Roughly speaking, `\midaligned{...}` is equivalent to `\hbox to equivalent to `\raggedcenter`, which in turn is equivalent to setting `\leftflush` and `\rightflush` to `1fil`.